# Simple Shader with OpenGL 'Mix' function does not work

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I have a simple shader code. 
I pass in two image texture (NOTE: One is samplerExternalOES and other one is sampler2D).

The first texture 'sTexture' is the original image i get from a camera frame. 
The second texture 'sTexture2' is a mask i get from the cpu.

The shader is as follows:

```
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 originalrgb = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
    vec4 floodfillimage = vec4((texture2D(sTexture2, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);

    /*Code To Colour Input Image with Blue Tint Color*/
    vec4 c = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1); 
    vec4 inputColor = vec4((texture2D(sTexture, v_TexCoord).rgb), 1.0);
    float average = (inputColor.r + inputColor.g + inputColor.b) / 3.0;
    vec4 grayscale = vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
    vec4 colorizedOutput = grayscale * c ;

    /*Code To mix original image with blue coloured based on another floodfilledimage passed in */
    gl_FragColor = mix(originalrgb.rgba, colorizedOutput.rgba, floodfillimage.r);
}
```

The error i recieve is glerror 1282, which means GL_INVALID_OPERATION. I've debugged and found out this happens on the mix function line.

**NOTE:**
If I change the last line to `gl_FragColor = mix(originalrgb.rgba, colorizedOutput.rgba, 0.5);`, it works.

So, why is it that the code panics when i do floodfillimage.r?

Thank You.

**EDIT**
I've tested both textures passed in (ie, i just rendered them to gl_FragColor) and they both are the image they're suppose to be

Comment: Which GPU are you using?

Comment: I'm doing this using OpenGL on an Android Device.

Comment: do you think it could be because of samplerExternalOES vs sampler2D?

Comment: When you set the third parameter of mix to 0.5, you're allowing the compiler to remove sTexture2 entirely. So I suspect there's some compiler bug relating to using both a sampler2D and a samplerExternalOES that you're sidestepping. As an aside, it seems like an odd move to initialize inputColor by sampling sTexture again rather than just copying originalrgb - unlikely to relate to your problem though. Also, what OpenGL call generates GL_INVALID_OPERATION? And can you respond to Rabbid76?

Comment: Another thought - are you definitely setting the sampler2D to your regular texture and the samplerExternalOES to your camera texture? If you get them the wrong way around because your code to determine the order is buggy then that could cause a GL_INVALID_OPERATION somewhere. (you can't assume sTexture will be index 0 and sTexture2 index 1 just because that's the order in the shader)

Comment: @Columbo even if i assume the other way, that wouldn't make this throw an error? where would that cause an GL_INAVLID_OPERATION?

Comment: I guess at the draw call. Where are you getting the GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Answer (score 0):

The shader looks legal to me and compiles successfully with various offline compilers, so I suspect you have hit a driver bug on the device you are using.

Comment: do you think it could be because of   samplerExternalOES vs  sampler2D? I'm doing this on an Android Device

Comment: how can i know for sure if its a bug on the driver? @solidpixel